# Searching/Filtering users using Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to construct a single filter query to retrieve all users whose names start with the letter "m" and who have the "Manager" role?

Comment: What do you mean by "the 'Manager' role"?

Comment: The question really comes down to whether a single filter can retrieve users based on a role along with a starts with filter.  The "manager" role was just an example.

Comment: Are you looking for all users that belong to a given Group?